# Bmesh - Append selected vertices to a List (Working script not "Reloading" correctly)

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

In Blender2.79,the script below calculates the selected vertices and stores them in a list.
As there were issues with calculating these vertices directly on a mesh instance ,the object's mesh had to be converted to a **"bmesh"** instance.

When the ***`script is run it works fine in the "First run"`***.

But in the subsequent runs it gives the following error- `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'verts'`

Also,on updating the bmesh with `bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)`results in this error-  `ReferenceError: BMesh data of type BMesh has been removed`

How to resolve these bmesh errors?

```
#-------------------------MAIN SCRIPT--------------------------
#Select vertices of default cube in Edit mode

from os import system
system("cls")

import bpy 
import bmesh

scene = bpy.context.scene
ob = scene.objects.active
vert = ob.data.vertices

#Set default mode == Edit 
if bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll():
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

print("Active object = ",ob.name)
print("")

#Create Bmesh instance and calculate vertices 
print("Vert_selected")

me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me) 

vert_selected = [v.co for v in bm.verts if v.select] #AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'verts'   
for vs_s in vert_selected :
    print(vs_s)

bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bm.select_flush(True)


#bm.bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me) #If mode ==Object  -> ReferenceError: BMesh data of type BMesh has been removed (Uncommenting results in Blender crash)
bm.free() 
ob.update_from_editmode()

print("Script exited")
```

Comment: Recommend Don't access `Mesh.vertices` in edit mode.  use edit mode bmesh for this. Can update the mesh from editmode with `context.object.update_from_editmode()` If using foreach get it returns a list of values eg [True, False, True, False] .  The list needs to be correct size.`v_selected = [False] * len(verts)` and is populated (not resized) by the call.  Use `if v.select:`  no need to check against `True`

Comment: On using the Bmesh module  on a existing object , only to check for selected vertices gives an error refer- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178938/convert-existing-mesh-to-bmesh-attributeerror-module-bmesh-has-no-attribut  .However , on  creating a new vert on a selected mesh using Bmesh module works fine .Should Bmesh be only  used when creating new verts ?

Comment: No Re the refer, I would accept the given answer. There is a big difference between a bmesh instance and the bmesh module.  There are countless examples of using [edit mode bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html#bmesh.from_edit_mesh) to select or read selection.  Once again accessing Mesh.vertices in editmode is not the way to go. Blender makes a "mesh copy" to edit in edit mode, then writes back on mode toggle.  An edit mode bmesh is bound to the edit mesh.

Comment: I have already implemented the answer in my other question and am getting the errors(refer attached image).Already used edit_mode_mesh(),it does give the selected vertices but it also gives the following error;- AttributeError: 'BMesh' object has no attribute 'bmesh' on update_edit_mesh().The Bmesh is  set free() after this update command .Is  there any way to override this error?

Comment: I have posted the issue's with using Bmesh in the above question.

Comment: Recommend using autocomplete in the python console. You import `bmesh` if you then `bmesh = something_else` when you go to use it again, thinking it's the bmesh module ...   (`bm` is commonly used as a bmesh instance)  it is something else. Would look to stackexchange et al for the meaning of python errors.  Can get to The attribute error above `bm =  bmesh.new()` and then trying to use  `bm.bmesh`  Most of these errors are well explained and easilly  fixed by searching `python AttributeError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no change in the actual mesh,updating the mesh with update_edit_mesh() was not required.Also setting object context directly to "Edit"mode as opposed to a context mode_set poll() works.

Code can be found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178938/convert-existing-mesh-to-bmesh-attributeerror-module-bmesh-has-no-attribut/179105#answers).